# count on aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

this my query for aggregate in pymongo:

```python
db.connection_log.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        'login_time': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 6, 57)}
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'username': '$username',
            'ras_id': '$ras_id',
            'user_id': '$user_id'
        }, 
        'total': { '$sum': '$type_details.in_bytes'}, 
        'total1': {'$sum': '$type_details.out_bytes'}
    }}, 
    { '$sort': {'total': 1, 'total1': 1}}
])
```

How to count all result in aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of your aggregation pipeline:

```
$group: {
    _id:null,
    count:{
        $sum:1
    }
}
```

[SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Comment: This(count key) value returns the wrong result!
I need to all result(record) from aggregate for create pagination on my table.
so I two query for aggregate.one for current table,other for all record on criteria.
please help me for creation pagination.

Comment: @user3676300 then you will need two queries

Comment: yes of course. but how to set query for get all records in aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want your results with a total count combined then you can always just push the results into their own array:

```python
result = db.connection_log.aggregate([
    { '$match': {
        'login_time': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 6, 57)}
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'username': '$username',
            'ras_id': '$ras_id',
            'user_id': '$user_id'
        }, 
        'total': { '$sum': '$type_details.in_bytes'}, 
        'total1': {'$sum': '$type_details.out_bytes'}
    }}, 
    { '$sort': {'total': 1, 'total1': 1}},
    { '$group' {
        '_id': null,
        'results': { 
            '$push': {
               '_id': '$_id',
               'total': '$total',
               'total1': '$total1'
            }
        },
        'count': { '$sum': 1 }
    }}
])
```

And if you are using MongoDB 2.6 or greater you can just `'$push': '$$ROOT'` instead of actually specifying all of the document fields there.

But really, unless you are using MongoDB 2.6 and are explicitly asking for a cursor as a result, then that result is actually returned as an array already without adding an inner array for results with a count. So just get the length of the array, which in python is:

```python
len(result)
```

If you are indeed using a cursor for a large result-set or otherwise using [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) to "page" results then you will need to do two queries with one just summarizing the "total count", but otherwise you just don't need to do this.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Neil. 
Your solution worked for me. But in terms of performance and how quickly is it the best?

Comment: @user3676300 There would not be much difference between altering the aggregation statement as shown and what you already have. That said, I wasn't really recommending it and was otherwise pointing out that the likely case is that your results are already and array of documents so you can just use the `len()` function from python anyway. You should not need to issue an aggregate statement again just to get the count the results unless you are implementing "paging" as described.